# Did I use the `Process` class correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have some code:

```
If StartProcess = True Then
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(Execution)
    If ProcessPath <> "" Then startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ProcessPath
    If ProcessArguments <> "" Then startInfo.Arguments = ProcessArguments
    NumProcesses += 1
    ExecutedProcesses(ProcessIndex) = Process.Start(startInfo)
    ProcessIndex += 1
    Executed = True
Else
    Executed = False
End If
```

I assume that if I put the process's path (the directory that the process is found in) as the value for `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` that the program will try to start the process from that directory. Is that true.

Comment: Why don´t you just try it by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

> I assume that if I put the process's path (the directory that the process is found in) as the value for startInfo.WorkingDirectory that the program will try to start the process from that directory. Is that true.

That depends. There are three scenarios according to these two MSDN documentation entries: [**`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), [**`ShellExecute` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

1. If the `UseShellExecute` property is `True` (default)

   > ...the WorkingDirectory property specifies the location of the executable. If WorkingDirectory is an empty string, the current directory is understood to contain the executable.

   - If the process path you specify is relative (e.g. `myapp.exe`) it will look for the process in the `WorkingDirectory` path. However, if the process path is absolute (e.g. `C:\Program Files\My App\myapp.exe`) it will start it from there and simply let the new process's working directory be what you specified.
2. If the `UseShellExecute` property is `False`

   > ...the WorkingDirectory property is not used to find the executable. Instead, its value applies to the process that is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

The working directory of a process is the directory that counts as its current folder. For instance, if you start Command Prompt (cmd) in Windows 7, its working directory will usually be your user path (e.g. `C:\Users\Vincent`). Whereas if you start cmd as an administrator, the working directory will be `C:\Windows\System32`.

---

As a side note, these checks you have are pretty useless:

```
If ProcessPath <> "" Then startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ProcessPath
If ProcessArguments <> "" Then startInfo.Arguments = ProcessArguments
```

If your variables *are* empty, then the `startInfo`'s properties will just be `Nothing`, which doesn't make any difference than an empty string in this case. Thus, removing the `If`-statements is fine:

```
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ProcessPath
startInfo.Arguments = ProcessArguments
```